# How can I copy certain sets of records from one MySQL database to another?

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to pull certain records from a remote production MySQL database into a local dev MySQL database. The production database is many GB in size and it is impractical to use a copy for reproducing/fixing/testing bugs in our product.

The production database contains many tables and is set up in a somewhat relational manner. There is a primary key 'customer_id' that ties every record in every table that is associated with a particular customer, to that customer. Both databases have the same name, let's call it "mydb". The data of interest is in, let's say, "myschema". The schemas are identical.

**How do I find all of the tables with customer data, select the records in each of those tables that relate to a particular customer(customers_id), and insert those records into the corresponding tables in the local db.** No worries about overwriting an existing customer_id, let's assume that for various reasons that situation will never arise.

So far I have managed to find all of the tables of interest using the following in MySQL workbench connected to my local db:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME IN ('customers_id') AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myschema';
```

At one time I had expanded on this to also query and find all of the rows where, for example, 'customers_id'='123' but I lost that and can't find my way back to that SQL statement.

I am not a DB expert by any stretch of the imagination, though from past experience I'm sure I could use perl and DBI or Python and the MySQL connector to ultimately get what I want but ideally I would like to do all of this with a SQL statement. The reason for this is that there are many developers in need of this capability and they would all have to install updated perl and perl modules or install the MySQL connector since the default VM images are lacking these bits.

TL;DR: The bolded text above is the core question I would like answered.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33931

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Writing a script is of course one option, though I was hoping MySQL could handle more of the work.

pt-archiver does not look like a good solution, since it appears to only work on a table at a time plus it wants to delete the original data. I have over 150 tables returned by the above query and I would have to make a system call for each, run pt-archiver in dry run mode, capture the output... That's way too kludgy even for me.

I would rather cobble together a script to do all of the work, but I really prefer to get MySQL to do more of the work as I mentioned above.

Comment: Have you tried using phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench? Also check this- http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/importing-into-mysql-from-other-databases.html

Comment: Yes I have... no joy so far. Perhaps if I could get back to the query that found all of the records that I wanted I could get somewhere with it but it's looking like a Python or PHP script is the answer. Thanks for the Navicat link, unfortunately that looks like too blunt an instrument for what I want and it's expensive to boot.

Comment: It would take me some time to write the complete query for you and I am caught up with some work right now. In the meantime, check out- http://easyquerybuilder.com/. Might help you in getting your work done. :)